# Height of Recursion Tree for $T(n, k) = T(n/2, k) + T(n, k/4) + kn$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computer-science, recursive-algorithms, recursion

If we use a recursion tree for solving  $$\begin{cases} T(*,1)=T(1,*)=a \\ T(n,k)=T(n/2,k)+T(n,k/4)+kn \end{cases}$$

What is the height of the recursion tree?

Any idea or solution highly appreciated.

Comment: That second recurrence only makes sense when $n$ and $k$ are multiples of $2$ and $4$ respectively. What if they aren't?

Comment: That leaves the $k/4$ still. Could you include more context about what $T(n,k)$ is counting?

Comment: @MounaMokhiab Show us how much you are able to do by yourself.  What is the height in the $T(*, 1)$ case?  What are the heights in the cases $$\begin{array} {c|c|c} T(2,4) & T(2,16) & T(2, 64) \\ \hline T(4,4) & T(4,16) & T(4, 64) \\ \hline T(8,4) & T(8,16) & T(8, 64) \end{array}$$

Comment: Got something from the answer below?

Comment: If you are waiting for somebody to prove that $T(n,k)$ is $O(\log n+\log k)$, then, as already mentioned, you are in for a loooong wait...

Comment: You can read [enter link description here][1] [1]:https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/136885/accurate-height-of-recursion-tree-for-given-recursion/136895#136895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $(i,j)$, consider $$t(i,j)=2^{-i}4^{-j}T(2^i,4^j),$$ then $t(i,0)=t(0,j)=a$ for every nonnegative $(i,j)$ and, for every positive $(i,j)$, $$t(i,j)=\tfrac12t(i-1,j)+\tfrac14t(i,j-1)+1.$$

Let $\ell\geqslant1$. If $t(i,j)\leqslant C$ for every $(i,j)$ such that $i+j=\ell-1$, then, for every $(i,j)$ such that $i+j=\ell$, $t(i,j)\leqslant\frac12C+\frac14C+1$, that is, $t(i,j)\leqslant C$ under the condition that $C\geqslant\max\{4,a\}$.

Assume that $a\gt0$. The computation above proves that $T(2^i,4^j)\leqslant C2^i4^j$ for every positive positive $(i,j)$ and for some $C$ large enough depending on $a$. On the other hand, every $T(n,k)$ is positive hence $T(n,k)\geqslant nk$ for every $n\geqslant2$ and $k\geqslant2$. To sum up, on the range $n\geqslant2$ and $k\geqslant2$, $$T(n,k)=\Theta(nk).$$
This approach works for every recursion $$T(n,k)=T(\alpha n,k)+T(n,\beta k)+\gamma nk,$$ provided $(T(1,k))$ and $(T(n,1))$ are bounded and $$\alpha+\beta\lt1.$$

Comment: Interesting. One may note that, if $a\gt0$ then every $T(n,k)\gt0$ hence, skipping most of the RHS of the recursion yields $T(n,k)\geqslant nk$ for every $(n,k)$ such that $n\geqslant2$ and $k\geqslant2$.

Comment: $$T(n,k)=T(n/2,k)+T(n,k/4)+nk\implies T(n,k)\gt nk$$

Comment: To show that $T(n,k)=O(\log n+\log k)$ after I got a proof that $T(n,k)=\Theta(nk)$... I am afraid this is slightly too postmodern for me.

Comment: Did you get the VERY SIMPLE argument showing that this is IMPOSSIBLE? I hope so.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Sure--now that they modified the question... Sorry but I am not ready to play at these games.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani No problem, many casual readers would have reacted like you did...

Comment: I am afraid our next exchanges shall not be very fruitful if you continue with this kind of approach...

Comment: "what kind of approach, I'm sure you answer is wrong" This kind of approach. Do you think anybody can feel inclined to help you when they see the kind of unwarranted slur you throw at those who did? Your choice, but anyway, I am out. (Unless, by chance, you change your mind and decide to discuss the mathematics of the question instead of insulting people.)